# Raspberry pi does not display unicode characters

Tags: terminal

I tried to install [Mapscii](https://github.com/rastapasta/mapscii) on a raspberry pi, but for some reason the list of character that it is able to display seems limited. I've Jessie light installation, no GUI, but the strange thing is that i've tried to connect different display to the pi, and i always got squares character instead of the unknow ones (mainly braille characters), except that it properly display the everything trough a ssh connection.

Does someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: To me it sounds like the used font does not support all the characters you use. Have you tried to connect via SSH and see if it still does not work?

Comment: yes, i think is exactly that, indeed in ssh works fine. so what can i do? i heard of fbterm, or passing to the X environment, but i there a way to just install a more extended font?

Comment: Including a link to [mapscii ... is this one correct?](https://github.com/rastapasta/mapscii) may be a good idea so people know a little bit more about what you are asking...

Comment: yes it is actually, i've inserted it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

MAPscii homepage tells you in the first sentence than it needs an xterm-compatible terminal. Braille characters are unicode (they really should've called it MAPunicode and not MAPscii), and the default font management system (`fontconfig`) is part of X. There are alternatives (google `tinyfont`, `ft2tf` and  `fbpad`) but by far the easiest solution would be to install `xterm` (which will pull the whole X GUI system) or `fbterm` (which will pull `fontconfig` and all its dependencies). You can also configure your virtual console to use unicode using [`/etc/sysconfig/console`](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.3/chapter07/console.html) or [`unicode_start`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unicode_start), but you still need to install unicode fonts for this to have the desired effect.

You probably run your SSH client in either Windows (putty) on in X environment (inside xterm), that's why MAPscii works via SSH.

Comment: first of all thanks. Anyway i tried fbterm but with little success, documentation is really quite technical for a beginner. Initially i was only getting:
**stdin isn't a interactive tty!**
(from ssh)
Then i tried:
**fbterm <> /dev/tty1**
Learning in the while about stdin, stdout and ttys. But it was anyway quite messy, with two cursors, and unable to stream that or other node based app on it, or to set it as default. If you have some advise that would be my first choice.

Comment: About **/etc/sysconfig/console** or **unicode_start**, are those something requiring fbterm as well or a just setting the standard linux console being able to visualize those glyps?

Comment: @piLeoni I think you have asked a follow-up question which got migrated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/467315/106927). I answered that, though I only found it years later.

Comment: Note that `fbterm` can run an arbitrary program inside it without the need to hijack `/dev/tty1`. You could just run `fbterm mapscii` or something along the lines.

Answer (score 0):

To get the braille characters, install the console-braille console font:

```
sudo apt install console-braille
```

I recommend to do the next step over SSH, to undo changes if the console stops working. Edit the file `/etc/default/console-setup` to look like this:

```
# CONFIGURATION FILE FOR SETUPCON

# Consult the console-setup(5) manual page.

ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]"

CHARMAP="UTF-8"

CODESET="guess"
FONTFACE="Terminus"
FONTSIZE="8x16"

VIDEOMODE=

# The following is an example how to use a braille font
#FONT='lat9w-08.psf.gz brl-8x8.psf'
FONT='Lat15-Terminus16.psf.gz brl-16x8.psf'
```

Back on the console, load the new font settings:

```
setupcon
```

If the console now looks funny, revert your changes over SSH and use `setupcon` again. Check that your chosen fonts are present in `/usr/share/consolefonts/`.

This still won't give you the full unicode range of characters, but at least you'll have both regular Latin and braille characters now. Which should be fine for MapSCII (and other tools which want to display graphs with braille characters).